# Python self argument

Tags: python, self

I have been coding in Java for years and my school here teaches Python, and I'm having a lot of trouble with it. My professor has asked us to create Connect4 in python and to start with these two methods:

```
def __init__( self, width, height ): 
self.width = width 
self.height = height 
self.data = [] # this will be the board 

for row in range( self.height ): 
    boardRow = [] 
    for col in range( self.width ): 
        boardRow += [' '] 
    self.data += [boardRow] 

def __repr__(self): 
#print out rows & cols 
    s = '' # the string to return 
    for row in range( self.height ): 
        s += '|' # add the spacer character 
        for col in range( self.width ): 
            s += self.data[row][col] + '|' 
        s += '\n' 

    #print out separator 
    #your code here 

    # print out indices of each column 
    # using mod if greater than 9, 
    # for spacing issues 
    #your code here

    return s # return it
```

I don't understand the `self` argument, I've read lots about it and nothing seems to make sense to me. I was hoping someone could give me a little explanation of what `self` is doing in this function, and why my professor is saying that the first function only two arguments are given but there are clearly three.

Any help/explanations would be greatly appreciated!

[Here](http://lang.encs.vancouver.wsu.edu/CS_121/assignments/assign9.pdf) is where I got those functions.

Comment: Have you looked at this?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/748858

Comment: `self` is the instance of your class.  It is implicitly (or explicitly, depending on your viewpoint) passed as the first argument to every method.  It is just like `this` in java, but you explicitly have to name it as the first argument to every method.

Comment: I've edited your code (checkit, I hope it's correct ;) because it was wrongly indented and indents with Python are extremely important ;)

Comment: Not to be rude but I think it was actually right before, i'm getting indentation errors now :s Also yes i've read through the 'self' explained thing but i guess i'm still not understanding or missing something.. I'll do some more research.

Comment: `__init__ ` still is indented wrong ... he fixed some of your code ... (the indentation was probably fine for your system... but not for how stack overflow formatted it ...

Comment: If you can tell us what specifically you don't understand from the "self explained" link, that would make a good question. In a single sentence, Java magically allows you to use `this` in an instance method, whereas Python requires you to pass `self` so you can use it, because ["Explicit is better than implicit"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: What I don't understand is say I try and use the first function which takes 2 arguments, 3 with self included, what do i type in? If i type this in the shell "__init__(6,7)" it tells me it needs 3 arguments, but I don't think I'm supposed to be setting self to an int am I?

Answer (score 1):

when calling a method on a class it passes the class instance as the first argument to the method , typically programmers name this argument self, but it can be named whatever

```
class CheckMeOut:
    def class_func(self):
        print self

    def class_func1(s):
         print s

    def class_func2(xyz):
         print xyz

c = CheckMeOut() #create Instance
c.class_func()
c.class_func1()
c.class_func2()
```

**or just look at the link mgilson supplied**